# Sending a message to console using socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to just send a test message to the console upon a button click, it doesn't show any messages tho.

Here's the code:

Server:

```
socket.on('testButton', function() {
    console.log("Button pressed!");
});
```

JS Client onclick:

```
 socket.emit('testButton');
```

Client:

```
 SOCKET.on('testButton', function () {
     console.log("test");
 });
```

Updated code:

Javascript

```
    $(".setnumber").on("click", function() {
            socket.emit('testButton');
    });
```

HTML

```
    <div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px"><a class="setnumber">Set</a></div>
    </div>
```

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('testButton', function() {
        console.log("Button pressed!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have the entire code section, including the HTML?

Comment: Cant tell anything without a good piece of code. Please post some more code

Comment: Updated some code, idk what else to show you, I know that the onclick is triggering, and I'm new to NodeJS & Socket.IO so I'm just trying to display a message when the button is clicked in the putty console.

Comment: You should show the code you used for socket-io initialization at client and server end

Comment: var io = require('socket.io')(8000);

Comment: Open the browser debug window and check if there is any error message. On the server side you could also log to the console when there is a new connection.